# Background image on BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry

I want to have a background image and being able to put `LabelField`, `PasswordEditField` or `EditField` over it.
Unfortunately, only `EditField` displays properly, but `LabelField` doesn't display at all.
`PasswordEditField` displayed but with a white background.

Comment: Guys this is very old question!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To display a label field, there should be some text set.

```
LabelField label=new LabelField("Text");
```

If there is no text, then it won't display anything.